# Неправильное выполнение условия

Tags: c#, unity3d, компилятор

В условии одно из значений — `false`, другое — `true` (получаемое в тернарном операторе), но тело условия всё равно выполняется.

В тернарном операторе `x = true`, `_x = true`; в массиве `is_wall` последнее значение — `false`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему происходит данная аномалия?

```
float height = 0.16f;
float width = 0.06f;
float distancex = 0.06f;
float distancey = 0.2f;
bool x = Vector2.left==direction || Vector2.right==direction ? true : false;
RaycastHit2D[] hits = new RaycastHit2D[3];
bool[] not_null = new bool[3];
bool[] is_wall = new bool[3];
hits[0] = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction);
hits[1] = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position+(x?new Vector3(0,height):new Vector3(width,0)), direction);
hits[2] = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + (x ? new Vector3(0, -height) : new Vector3(-width, 0)), direction);
for(int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
{
    not_null[i] = hits[i].collider != null;
    is_wall[i] = not_null[i] ? hits[i].collider.tag.Equals("wall") : false;
}

if (!not_null[0] && !not_null[1] && !not_null[2])
      return true;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    bool _x = hits[i].distance <= distancex;
    bool _y = hits[i].distance <= distancey;

    if (is_wall[i] && x ? _x : _y)
    {
        return false;
    }
}           
return true;
```

Comment: _компилятор всё равно переходит_ - компилятор никуда не переходит, он компилирует и только.

Comment: непонятно. вас не устраивает, что правильно отрабатывает тернарный оператор? или что за аномалия? `_x = true`, а `x`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский x=true

Comment: @АлексейШиманский насколько я понял у него массив bool и при `i == 2` получается `is_wall[2] == false`, но в `if` все равно заходит...

Comment: @AGS17, да, именно так

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH по идее такого в принципе быть не может. Запишите может видео как вы дебажите...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что ваша проблема в следующем: ваш код

```
is_wall[i] && x ? _x : _y
```

интерпретируется компилятором как

```
(is_wall[i] && x) ? _x : _y
```

а вам нужно

```
is_wall[i] && (x ? _x : _y)
```

Поставьте явные скобки.

Comment: Если бы `_y` был бы всё время `true`, то ошибку можно было еще долго не найти)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Ага! Обычно у `_x` тип не `bool`, и неправильный порядок просто не скомпилируется.

Comment: Гениально! Даже не подумал об этом :)

Comment: @AGS17: Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD 2 часа с этим сидел, думал уже всё бросить, спасибо, что спасли мой проект! :)

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH: Пожалуйста! Рад, что угадал причину проблемы :)